plyer notificationon OS X app_icon attrib not showing icon
I'm trying to configure some notifications on my python application running on OS X (latest version), message show correctly but the icon it's not showing in notification. It shows always the python rocket.
I've only deploy plyer lib.
I've tried relative path and absolute path but don't work. Image is a PNG and works fine in application.
notification.notify(title='Inicio', message='Inicio Juego', app_name='OctoPus', app_icon='./assets/player.png')

I've tried path with . or without, don't work.
